# What is Circle "Daira" in islamic point of view

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

Here in our area and in some other old villages people do **Circle "Daira"** to find something which is missing/stolen or somebody who is missing and they says that they can know what is its condition. I don't know how do they do it.

Is there any information related to Circle "diara" from Qur'an or Hadith or story from Sahaba?

> ***Circle "Diara"**
>
>   I tried to Google about diara but couldn't find related information and don't know what is it called in English so I am considering it Circle which is its meaning from our language.*

Comment: Daira? isnt that a tambourine?

Comment: Music Instrument?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could tell us where "our area" and "our language" is.

Answer (score 1):

Daira is actually means something very close to circle as a mathematical term. The Turkish word used for daira is "daire". Daira is actually a circle with its inside area.

About what you actually asked, I heard that behavior before. And I also heard that its a superstition. Probably some tradition coming from ancient magic issues. Also I doubt it will really work.

Dua and physical search is the best solution my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of something as such. It sounds like something they made up and co-incidentally worked couple of times.

I know if you lose something and pray that you find it or  say:
 "اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم" 
"A`ūdhu billāhi min ash-shaitāni r-rajīmi"
the likeliness of finding it increases. But nothing specific.

Answer (score 0):

The keywords you used seem to be regional.

If they pertain to some magic, then

> The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “Whoever blows on knots practices magic, and whoever practices magic is a mushrik (polytheist).” (Reported by At-Tabarani)

May the creator guide us all.